# What is Generated Mapping and UV Mapping? And what is the difference?

Tags: texturing, uv

Well, basically that's it. What are this texture mapping modes? Is there pros and cons of each one?

Comment: Shortly (and roughly), Generated Mapping is mapping generated by Blender, UV Mapping is one generated by you

Comment: Unwrapped texture coordinates explanation refers to UV Mapping mode?